# systemd service causes sudo crash

Tags: services, systemd

I installed [opensnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) as a service, so it automatically runs on system startup.

I then changed my mind and deleted the `.service` file, but have forgotten to `disable` the service before deletion. Now On every system startup my sudo crashes cause it still tries to run the service with this line `sudo -HE opensnitchd`

How can I deactivate it, the `.service` file is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Her is my solution

```
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```